# Adobe After effects watch folder render all composition

Tags: after-effects, adobe-media-encoder, after-effects-scripting

I am saving an After effects file in a watch folder which is being watched by Adobe media encoder using extendscript , the problem is all the compositions are rendered to a video by adobe media encoder, I want to instruct the AME to export only one composition(the main comp) from the project, Is there any way around to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that only the comps you want rendered are in the top level of the project. If there are compositions that you don't want rendered, such as subcomps, put them in a folder in your project window

[image]